# VPN and IPv6 support

Tags: dns, ipv6

I want to do some IPv6 testing of my home LAN and want to request connections from an IP outside the LAN.

What is the best way to do this? I have been able to do some IPv4 testing using VPN but I haven't found a VPN provider that offers IPv6.

Is there anything about IPv6 to make VPN unneccessary, difficult, or impossible?

Comment: Sorry, voted to close as as this is asking for a product recommendation.   Your second paragraph does not make sense.

Comment: @davidgo Okay yup. I'll rephrase.

Comment: @davidgo Fixed, I hope.

Comment: I'm not particularly qualified to answer the question, but I have upvoted it and voted to re-open which is as much as I can do.   I also comment that its definitely possible to tunnel IPV6, and doing so would conceptually be no different to IPV4.  (Ref: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IPv6). IPV6 is normally delivered over IPV4 by straight tunnelling rather then using a VPN.  It sounds like you are looking for an IPV6 tunnel broker.  A starting point may be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IPv6_tunnel_brokers.

Comment: Eh, there's really not much of a difference between "tunnel" and "VPN". Protocols which have encryption or authentication are usually grouped in the latter, protocols without are usually grouped in the former, but that's more or less it.